# How to "publish" angular 2 app

Tags: node.js, angular, ip, port

I wanted to ask how to "publish" my angular2 app. Now, I was using npm start to start my development server. But what do I have to do to publish the app,  so I don’t need to leave the console open with npm start?

And how to point the basic IP to the angular2 port? 
I have smth.  like this:
123.456.678:3000
instead of
123.456.678

I searched on the Internet and ng2 docs but I didn't find an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to "publish" your app you'll have to serve the content after running the `build` command (if you could provide more information about the cli tool that you're using, i could give a more detailed answer about the build command...)
anyways, it should build to a folder called `dist` or `build`.

To not need to keep your console running your app you can host your app in some web host (it can be free like [github pages](https://pages.github.com/) which will give you a custom url: `http://yourUsername.github.io/yourApp`) or continue reading if you want to leave your console running...

About your IP `123.456.789` it will be needed to use a server like `Caddy` (which is really easy to use) or alternatives like: `apache` or `nginx`.

You will need to serve your app through the port `80` so no custom port is needed (`:3000`) in your url.

you can use this [Caddyfile](https://caddyserver.com/docs/getting-started) to start with

```
# port 80 so no port is needed in the url
# change "dist" to your distribution or app folder name!

:80 {
    root ./dist
}
```

save the code in a file called `Caddyfile` and run `caddy` from your console!